# Conditionnally output a long table depending on output type?

Tags: luatex

I have a document to be outputed both in PDF (using `lualatex`) and in HTML (using `make4ht`).

The document contains a long table, so I use the `tabu` package in PDF. Unfortunately, the package seems to not work with `tex4ht`. So I use at several places the logic :

```
\ifdefined\HCode
% HTML branch...
\else
% PDF branch...
\fi
```

This works well, except for long tables.

Here is my MWE :

```
\ifdefined\HCode
    \documentclass{book}
\else
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{tabu}
\fi

\begin{document}

% Define table header differently if we are produced HTML or PDF
\ifdefined\HCode
  %for HTML
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  A & B \\
  \hline
\else 
  % For PDF
  \begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {|X|X|}
  \hline
  \rowfont A & B \\ \hline 
  \hline
  \endhead
\fi

1 & 2 \\ \hline
3 & 4 \\ \hline

% Close correctly the table depending on output
\ifdefined\HCode
  % for HTML
  \end{tabular}
\else 
  % For PDF
  \end{longtabu}
\fi

\end{document}
```

On the paper this should just run fine and it works when using `make4ht doc.tex`.

However, when executing `lualatex doc.tex`, I get :

```
Runaway argument?
\global \advance \c@LT@chunks \@ne \global \LT@rows \z@ \setbox \z@ \vbox \ETC.

! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \LT@nofcols.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.35      \end{tabular}

?
```

Note that if I comment out the `\ifdefined` logic and run separately the PDF or HTML logic, it works fine in both case. It only fails when doing this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new environment in different ways according to the engine:

```
\ifdefined\HCode
    \documentclass{book}
\else
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{tabu}
\fi

\ifdefined\HCode
\newenvironment{maybelongtable}
  {\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}\hline A&B \\\hline}
  {\end{tabular}}
\else
\newenvironment{maybelongtable}
  {\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {|X|X|}
  \hline
  \rowfont A & B \\ \hline 
  \hline
  \endhead}
  {\end{longtabu}}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{maybelongtable}
1 & 2 \\ \hline
3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{maybelongtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Neat! This is also much cleaner as I may have more than one of these tables. thanks